# how can I solve this problem ? : At least one numeric character allowed without regex

Tags: javascript, character

```
if(password.search(/[0-9]/)){
    document.getElementById('fpasswords').innerHTML="*atleast one numeric character";
    return false;
}
```

here i used regex but i don't want to use it so what's the solution?

Comment: can you show any attempt (non-regex attempt)?

Comment: There is no way to do so! You must make use of Regex.

Comment: Yes there is a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check each character with the function isNaN, this function returns false is it's a numeric character and true if it's not:

```
const str = 'Papayas1';

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  
  if(!isNaN(str.charAt(i))) console.log('this is a number')
  else console.log('this is not a number')
}
```